# Weird JSpinner behaviour

Tags: java, swing, transparent, jspinner

I encountered the weirdest behaviour of swings JSpinner. 
The spinner looks like this (the component in the middle is the spinner):

[image]

As you notice, it has no text and no buttons and it behaves like a disabled JTextField.
I tried `setEnable(true)`, but nothing happend.

The JSpinner is on a transparent JPanel, wich is added to a JFrame with a background image. I suspect that this has something to do with this problem.

Note that the same behavior occurs with a JComboBox, but every other Component (like a JTextField or a JSlider) works perfectly fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: hard to tell without seeing the code ...

Comment: See also [opacity](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#props).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `synchronized(this.getTreeLock()) {
this.validateTree() }`.

Comment: thanks. I used `this.validate()`. I dont really know whats the difference, but validate tree worked.